# is Tether USDT centralized or decentralized coins?

Tags: usdt, tether

Seem like Tether USDT is  centralized crypto.

From Forbes

"
Tether is a centralized crypto, whereas Bitcoin is decentralized by not being linked to any real-world currencies. For that reason, in theory, Tether's value should remain more stable than Bitcoin's. Cryptocurrencies that are not pegged to a real-world asset or currency are subject to market volatility."

On the other hand, From tether.to

"Tether on the Ethereum blockchain, as an ERC20 token, is a newer transport layer, which now makes Tether tokens available in Ethereum smart contracts or decentralized applications on Ethereum."

I believe decentralized applications on Ethereum is different than decentralized coins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tether (USDT) is a centralized crypto. Tether tokens being available in Ethereum smart contracts or decentralized applications on Ethereum doesn't make it decentralized. USDT is not mined and it is not decentralized. It has a central entity, the company Tether, that issues (mints) and destroys (burns) USDT tokens.

Answer (score 0):

USDT is decentralized in technology and centralized in decision-making. The underlying technology of USDT is built on a decentralized blockchain network, which is distributed across many nodes and computers, and no single entity has complete control over it